# Retrieve from database using PHP and pass to javascript as JSON

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dojo

I am creating a weather widget using javascript . In this widget the user can select the town they wish to see and the widget will display outlook , min and max temperature without refreshing using ajax . I have stored the city information in a database and had written PHP script to retrieve the data and pass it to js as JSON object

```
<?php

/**************************
 * code to connect to your database here
 */
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_select_db("weather", $con);


$town = $_GET['town'];

/***************************
 * 
 * Query the DB for weather information for the given town.
 * 
 * A PHP array object containing the weather data.
 * Return a JSON encoded version of the array to the browser.
 * 
 */
 $sql = "SELECT * from weather where town = $town";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $arr = array(
    "town"     => $row[town],
    "outlook"  => $row[outlook],
    "min_temp" => $row[min_temp],
    "max_temp" => $row[max_temp]
  );
}

echo json_encode($arr);

mysqli_close();
?>
```

And in js i want to show the weather only for selected town . How to parse the JSON object to get only the information of the town selected by the user . Like

```
if(jsondata == "sydney")
   return "sydney information";
```

I did this using DOJO  as

```
 var data;
  dojo.xhrGet({
    // The URL to request
    url: "PHP/weather.php?town=" + ntown,
    sync: true,
    handleAs: 'json',
    // The method that handles the request's successful result
    // Handle the response any way you'd like!
    load: function(result) {

      data = result;
    }
  });
  return data;
}
```

However , i dont want to use dojo . how do i do that . Any suggestions ?

Comment: if $town a string then query should be like this: `$sql = "SELECT * from weather where town = '$town'";  `

Comment: @ Awlad Liton $town is a php variable which gets the string from html

Comment: Instead of Dojo what do you want to use? Another library or?

Comment: @Ivanka Todorova just i want to use AJAX

Comment: you give the town to php. php then return only the town information. how does your result look like?

Comment: @sanketh its a assignment . i was asked to use only js and ajax

Comment: @Novalis sorry my mistake , it would return only the town specified , but how do i do it without dojo

Comment: its hard to say without seeing your return or your html. i try to do a generic answer

Comment: @Novalis Here is my html  pastebin.com/wbngYzhD and js       http://pastebin.com/jHqZT08M

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a select tag with id "town".

```
   <select id="town" onchange="handler(this)"></select>
```

Now, for the Javascript part. You need to use XMLHttpRequest to make an ajax call.

```
function handler(elem){
    var tname = elem.value;
    var request_url = "PHP/weather.php?town=" + tname;
    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 try{
  // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
  http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}catch (e){
  // Internet Explorer Browsers
  try{
     http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }catch (e) {
     try{
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }catch (e){
        // Something went wrong
        alert("Some error occured");
        return false;
     }
  }
 } 

http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
  if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
  {
    // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

    //Update your page here
   }
 }

 http_request.open("GET", request_url);
 http_request.send();

}
```

Comment: i followed this but cant able to update the result . Here is my html http://pastebin.com/wbngYzhD  and js http://pastebin.com/jHqZT08M

Comment: Your code still has jquery in it ! Shouldn't you be using plain javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <body>
        <div id="townInfo">
             <div id="town"></div>      
             <div id="outlook"></div>       
             <div id="min_temp"></div>      
             <div id="max_temp"></div>      
        </div>
        <script>
            var town = document.getElementById('town');
            var outlook = document.getElementById('outlook');
            var min_temp = document.getElementById('min_temp');
            var max_temp = document.getElementById('max_temp');

            var data;
            dojo.xhrGet({
                // The URL to request
                url: "PHP/weather.php?town=" + ntown,
                sync: true,
                handleAs: 'json',       
                load: function(result) {
                    data = result;
                    town.innerHtml = data['town'];
                    outlook.innerHtml = data['outlook'];
                    min_temp.innerHtml = data['min_temp'];
                    max_temp.innerHtml = data['max_temp'];
                }
           });

        </script>
        </body>
```

warning: not tested

Comment: oh, i thought this was for DOM add only. well